# Firebase Rules: Can I constrain a field to only update if another field is also changing?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I am trying to put together a for-fun, not-real-money "betting" site. The setup is basically as follows:

```
{ users: {
  $user_id: {
    balance: <number>,
    wagers: {
      $wager_id: {
        wager: <number>,
        bet_id: <string>,
        created_at: <number>,
        <etc>
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The problem is that I do not want the balance to change if the user is not placing a wager. I have a validation rule that keeps the wager from changing if the new balance doesn't match the math. That is useless however if the user can just update the balance to whatever they want. Here are the related rules:

```
{"rules":
  {
    ".read":"auth != null",
    ".write": false,
    "users": {
      "$uid": {
        ".write":"auth != null && auth.uid === $uid",
        "balance": {
          ".validate": "(!data.exists() && newData.val() === 100) || (data.exists() && newData.exists() && newData.isNumber() && newData.val() >= 0 && data.parent().child('wagers').val() !== newData.parent().child('wagers').val())"
        },
        "wagers": {
          "$wager_id": {
            "wager": {
              ".validate": "data.val() >=0 && ( 
                (data.exists() &&  
                  data.parent().parent().parent().child('balance').val() + data.val() - newData.val() === newData.parent().parent().parent().child('balance').val())
                ||
                (!data.exists() &&  
                  data.parent().parent().parent().child('balance').val() - newData.val() === newData.parent().parent().parent().child('balance').val())
              )"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

So you can see with this line, I am trying to make sure that `wagers` changed.

```
data.parent().child('wagers').val() !== newData.parent().child('wagers').val()
```

But it does not work, this statement always returns true.

Ideally, I would like to know the `$wager_id` of the changing wager from the context of `balance`. Even if the above rule worked, someone could still change the `created_at` of the `$wager_id` and it would validate. I have considered stuffing this into a temporary location during the same transaction (like at `user/$user_id/changing_wager`) and then removing it right afterwards, but that seems really hokey.

Can anyone enlighten me? :D

(To be clear: this is just a game, nothing is really at stake, and there will be a weekly server process that can run the math and catch cheaters. However, if I can figure out a solution that works with pure Firebase validation rules, that would be pretty awesome.)

Comment: Thinking about it, I'll probably wind up using a temporary id storage location that is accessible from the parent, something like "changing_wager_id". Wondering if there is a work-around that doesn't involve extra db calls.